# Auto adjusting the length of a Bézier curve to meet a predefined length without moving its end points

Tags: javascript, html, svg, bezier

I'm working on an SVG graphics program where the user can draw a Bézier curve and then define its length with text.  By default, when the user defines its new length, I want the endpoints to stay in the same position, and for the curvature of the line to adjust to accommodate the new length (for example, for a cubic bezier curve with points P0,...P3, I want P0 and P3 to stay stationary while the control points move, here's a supporting wikipedia image:  http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d0/Bezier_curve.svg/600px-Bezier_curve.svg.png).

I am already able to calculate the current length of the curve with svg.js, and have set up a function that will scale length of each control line (P0 -> P1, and P3 -> P2) by a constant to achieve the desired length.  This approach has mostly given me the results I'm looking for, but it seems like my scaling factor is off.  Based on reading A Primer on Bézier Curves, I have tried using newLength/oldLength as the scaling factor, and I have also tried (newLength/oldLength)^2, both of which got me closer to the user entered length, however I had to do this process 4-5 times to get me closer to the answer I was looking for.  I also recognize that this approach (control length scaling) is not full proof, and that there are several edge cases here that this doesn't account for, but I want to conditionally scale the length of this line based on whether the angle and/or length of the control lines is fixed.

I should add that the number of control points that the Bézier curve has is not necessarily fixed, but right now I'm only looking at the cubic case.  Higher precision and accuracy is ideal, however it's fine if it's off by a few pixels.

Comment: you have two degrees of freedom for each of the control points. What direction would you move them in? Just along the tangent from/to the end points (so P1 along P0--P1 and P2 along P2--P3)?

Comment: That's the preference, I'd even simplify it further by saying that they can both be scaled by the same amount.  The general idea is to only augment what the user has defined, so I figured that preserving the initial angle would be the most ideal solution.  Naturally, this exact strategy won't always work, but knowing the relationships/ranges for the control points would be ideal so I can design for the cases where that isn't necessarily going to be the best approach.

Comment: I'm not sure how changing the curve to a fixed length by moving the control points is "helping the user", since it changes the curve the user defined (it would make a lot more sense to instead restrict the start/end tangents so that the curves create aesthetic segments. Curve length gets in the way). That said, you're not going to get there with a linear scaling, since the arc length is an sqrt(4th order) expression. You probably want to do a binary search: offset the controls, check length. Too much? go back half distance. Check again. Too little? back half distance, etc. etc.

Comment: Binary searching has has O(log(n)) complexity, and converges on the correct length really quickly, so the only expensive part there would be the length recomputation, which if you absolutely need a "fixed length" curve (I'm still not sure why that's a good idea, but that aside) is an acceptable penalty.

Comment: Makes sense, sounds like a good strategy.  I'll try that approach, thanks for the help.